# Robot Framework AutoItLibrary - No keyword with name 'Control Send' found

Tags: python, autoit, robotframework

I'm encountering the error "No keyword with name 'Control Send' found whenever I run my Robot Test using AutoItLibrary.

It's really weird. Initially, after installing ActiveState Python, Robot Framework, and the AutoItLibrary the test worked with no errors. Then, after logging out of the Windows server, and re-running the same test, I encounter this issue.

The application does open, however, when I try to use other keywords, I encounter this issue.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue. I uninstalled AutoItLibrary (also, I deleted the AutoItLibrary in the following directories:
  C:\RobotFramework\Extensions\
  C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\

Re-installing AutoItLibrary and then running the script worked fine. Then, I logged-off again. After logging in again, I run the script, and the error was again encountered.

I have a feeling this has something to do with registering the AutoItX3.dll.

Comment: Temporary work around was to issue the command python setup.py install --force on the setup.py of autoitlibrary. There must be something that's getting reverted when I log off to the windows server. Hopefully, someone out there might give a clue as to what that is.

Comment: It's ``Control Command``